# Проблема с Google Maps на Android

Tags: android, google-maps-api, google-maps

По примеру, приведенному здесь, я создавал приложение, у меня здесь 2 файла (activity_main.xml и activity_maps.xml). В итоге я вставил фрагмент кода в content_main.

При запуске приложения через телефон, приложение падает и пишет “Приложение остановлено”. В чем проблема?

Вот краш:

> 12-17 22:59:15.899 1719-1719/? E/NotificationService: WARNING: In a future release this will crash the app: com.android.providers.downloads

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    static final LatLng TutorialsPoint = new LatLng(21 , 57);
    private GoogleMap googleMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        try {
            if (googleMap == null) {
                googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().
                        findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
            }
            googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
            Marker TP = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().
                    position(TutorialsPoint).title("TutorialsPoint"));
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        googleMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }
}
```

Comment: Вас же уже просили прикрепить код. Приложение останавливается из-за ошибки, а ошибка может быть где угодно. Инициализация гуглмэп это место где вы её имплементите.

Comment: Вы это имеете ввиду?

Comment: как связано "В итоге я вставил фрагмент кода в content_main" и то что у вас разметка все равно из activity_maps?

Comment: Ой извиняюсь, поправил... Просто сперва был контент а потом поменял на активити_мэпс проблема та же осталась...

Comment: Уточню на всякий случай. Вы же получили и добавили ключ для Google maps?

Comment: Какую версию google maps вы используете?

Comment: Да, ключ добавил. Последнюю, цифру нигде не нашел.

Comment: Теперь экран стал бежевым, и левом нижнем углу надпись Google...

Comment: Вы тестируете на реальном дивайсе или эмуляторе?

Comment: И на телефоне и на эмуляторе...

Comment: У вас какая то проблема с ключем/googleAPI вы где то допустили ошибку, так как приложение не может получиться доступ к картам. Код который вы предоставили ни как повлиять на это не может. Если сделать все правильно то даже 

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps); будет достаточно чтобы отобразить саму карту.

Comment: А еще есть другой способ, например скачать карту, а элементы на карте точнее маркеры, местонахождение будут работать в онлайне?

Comment: А для каких целей вам вообще нужна эта карта?

Comment: Для 2-х телефонов, один в машине будет другой у меня, то есть для слежения местонахождения машины...

Comment: Таких уже куча готовых приложений есть, но если вам интересно сделать самому просто используйте Intent, он вам и маршрут проложит самостоятельно.

Comment: Да, самому нужно сделать ну типа первый серьезный проект и сразу такие проблемы. Не понял насчет Интента, это вы про открытие окон то есть воспользоваться другими программами\картами..??

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы решить вашу задачу попробуйте вот это:

```
String uri = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=%f,%f(%s)&daddr=%f,%f (%s)", sourceLatitude, sourceLongitude, "Home Sweet Home", destinationLatitude, destinationLongitude, "Where the party is at");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
startActivity(intent);
```

Хотя для гибкости вашего приложения я бы все же рекомендовал, заново внимательно пройти туториал по установке google maps https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start. Вы очевидно упустили какую то на ваш взгляд не важную деталь которую не прикрепили к вопросу.